# Create new columns from aggregates of other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
   col1    col2  col3
0   tom     2    cash
1   tom     3    gas
2   tom     5    online
3   jerry   1    online
4   jerry   4    online
5   jerry   5    gas
6   scooby  8    cash
7   scooby  6    dogfood
8   scooby  1    cheese
```

easily obtained with:

```
data = {'col1': ['tom', 'tom', 'tom', 'jerry', 'jerry', 'jerry', 'scooby', 'scooby', 'scooby'],
'col2': [2,3,5,1,4,5,8,6,1],
'col3':['cash', 'gas', 'online', 'online', 'online', 'gas', 'cash', 'dogfood', 'cheese']}

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How would one group the data by `col1`, then as extra columns, get specific aggregates for specified values of `col3`.

As an example, say I want to group by `col1` and get the sum of the `gas`, `cash` and `online` fields for everyone in `col1`, like this.

```
col1    gas_sum    cash_sum    online_sum
tom        3          2             5
jerry      5          0             5
scooby     0          8             0
```

I am relatively new to pandas and the only way I can think of to do this is with a for loop through all the data, as `groupby`'s purpose is more to give the sum/mean of columns like `col2` in my example.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). We'll also use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to get only the values you're interested in and [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to change your column names:

```
# Values to sum
values = ['cash', 'gas', 'online']

df_out = (df.pivot_table(index='col1', columns='col3',
                         values='col2', aggfunc='sum',
                         fill_value=0)
 .reindex(columns=values, fill_value=0)
 .add_suffix('_sum'))
```

[out]

```
col3    cash_sum  gas_sum  online_sum
col1                                 
jerry          0        5           5
scooby         8        0           0
tom            2        3           5
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

we can chain `isin` `groupby` and `unstack`

```
df1 = df.loc[df["col3"].isin(["gas", "online", "cash"])].groupby(["col1", "col3"])[
    "col2"
].sum().unstack().fillna(0)

df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x : x + '_sum')

df1.columns.name = ''

print(df1)

        cash_sum  gas_sum  online_sum
col1                                 
jerry        0.0      5.0         5.0
scooby       8.0      0.0         0.0
tom          2.0      3.0         5.0
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks sir! Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: @Joram no problem, you could also just filter and use the `crosstab` or `pivot` functions which are much easier to read imo. good luck :)